# Help me put one eye drop

Tags: grammar

My eyes are red and need to put on eye drop.

> "Help me put one eye drop."
>
> "Help me drop an eye drop"

How to ask to drop an eye drop into eyes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maulik V is wrong. It should read this way:

> "Help me **put in** some eye drops."
>
> "Help me **put** some eye drops **in**."
>
> "Help me **put** some eye drops **in my eyes**."
>
> "Help me **apply** some eye drops (to my eyes)."

"Put in" in the reference "put in something" or "put something in" is a phrasal verb that means "to apply".  If you were to say,

> "Help me put some eye drops."

you would basically be saying,

> "Help me place some eye drops."

Well, place them where? Do you want me to place them in John's eyes? Margaret's eyes? What do you want?  It's the first sign of someone who doesn't understand the nuances of the language.  This isn't some small error either.  I would immediately give a look and reply with "Huh? What do you want me to do?" I would be confused for about five seconds before I figured out that the person is a foreigner and I applied the context; however, if a native speaker like my grandfather said that, I would definitely ask him, "What do you want me to do? I'm confused." I'm sure I would figure it out, but it would take longer because I wouldn't expect that error from a native speaker and I would think that he wanted something odd done with the eye drops.  It's just not said that way. It's like saying the following:

> "I looked the definition the word." ("I looked **up** the definition
>   **of** the word.")
>
> "I ran the bill on my friend's credit card." ("I ran **up** the bill
>   on my friend's credit card.")

The meaning is lost without these "particles" and I am left to figure it out by context.  This is a pain.  The particles matter.

**P.S.** As for one eye drop in each eye, you should say:

> "Help me put an eye drop in each of my eyes."
>
> "Help me put an eye drop in each eye (of mine)."
>
> "Help me put in my eye drops. One drop goes in each eye."

Comment: "Help me put some eye drops in my eyes." it that mean put in the eye some drop? The medicine is allow 1 drip in each eye. Help me put one eye drop in my eyes?

Comment: In that instance, "Help me put an eye drop in each of my eyes" or "Help me put in my eye drops. One drop goes in each eye."

Comment: I've added an answer for "one drop" in my answer, e12345678. I hope that will help you out.

Answer (score -2):

You can say...

> Help me put some eye drops (in my eyes) or  Please put me some eye drops.

Because, here you are *actually* referring to the **medicine** and not *literally a drop of that liquid*.

The medicine is *eye drops.*

[image: eye drops]

Comment: I disagree. I'd say, "Help me put **in** some eye drops" or "Help me put some eye drops **in**."

Comment: I won't say *in* after put! And, for the particle 'in' at the end, where else do you put eye drops! :) @NicholasCastagnola

Comment: Okay, your choice. It sounds odd to me though without "in". I would go "huh" if you said that to me; then I'd think about it and figure it out.

Comment: "put in" means "to apply". You apply eye drops; you don't just *put* eye drops. It really changes the entire meaning. Is English your native language? I am guessing not.

Comment: If you are a native speaker and this is the usage in your dialect, you need to say whay dialect that is. For American and (AFAIK) British English, it's simply not correct.